# How to specify alpha for both fill and colour geom_tile

Tags: r, ggplot2, alpha

I'm making a plot using geom_tile where I would like to specify the transparency of each tile based on a variable. However, when I specify alpha with `aes()`, it only applies to fill, not colour. This results in a plot where the lines between the tiles are darker than the tiles. Is there a way to also specify alpha for colour? Using geom_raster is not an option for me as this is for a map, and I would like to use a coordinate projection. Removing the colour specification makes the plot look washed out.

Here is some code that reproduces my issue.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)
library(reshape)

volcano3d <- melt(volcano) 
names(volcano3d) <- c("x", "y", "z") 
ggplot(volcano3d, aes(x, y, z = z,fill=z,color=z)) +
  geom_tile(aes(alpha=y))+
  theme_bw()
```

Comment: It seems like you should be able to do this with something like `scale_color_gradient(low = '#00000000', high = 'hotpink')`, but it sadly ignores the transparency specification (though it accepts it...)—maybe a colorspace issue.

Comment: You would think so, but I also found that there is no effect of specifying alpha in scale_color_gradient( ). It seems like there needs to be a separate alpha for colour and for fill.

Comment: Alpha is its own aesthetic, which is why `scale_alpha_continuous` exists. But yes, for `geom_tile`, it only affects fill, not stroke. The `scale_color_gradient` approach is a bit hacky, but looks like it fails because of the underlying color handling. A GitHub issue might be a possibility here if properly assembled, though it may be rejected as too much work.

Answer (score 6):

Like @alistaire, it seemed to me that the `geom_tile` tile borders should obey the `alpha` mapping, but they don't appear to. As a workaround, you could use `geom_segment` to draw line segments in the same locations where the borders should be. These segments do obey the `alpha` mapping.

In the code below, we first create a new data frame `segs` for drawing the segments. We could use the original data, but it's short one row and one column.

```
library(dplyr)

segs = expand.grid(x=(min(volcano3d$x)-1):max(volcano3d$x),
                   y=(min(volcano3d$y)-1):max(volcano3d$y)) %>%
  left_join(volcano3d)
```

To add the segments to the plot, we need to sort each time to get the x and y values in the right order for, respectively, vertical or horizontal segments. We also use `colour="#FFFFFF00"` in `geom_tile` to remove the default tile border.

```
ggplot(volcano3d, aes(fill=z, colour=z, alpha=y)) +
  geom_tile(colour="#FFFFFF00", aes(x, y)) +
  geom_segment(data=segs %>% arrange(x,y), 
               aes(x=x+0.5, xend=x+0.5, y=y+0.5, yend=lag(y)+0.5), size=0.2) +
  geom_segment(data=segs %>% arrange(y,x), 
               aes(x=x+0.5, xend=lag(x)+0.5, y=y+0.5, yend=y+0.5), size=0.2)
```

In the plot below, you can see the tile borders, but they fade along with the tiles themselves. The borders are a bit darker because they're drawn over the tiles, resulting in roughly double the opacity of the tiles alone.

[image]

If you want the tile borders to be less salient, you can scale down their `alpha` values relative to the tile alpha values.

```
ggplot(volcano3d, aes(fill=z, colour=z)) +
  geom_tile(colour="#FFFFFF00", aes(x, y, alpha=y)) +
  geom_segment(data=segs %>% arrange(x,y), 
               aes(x=x+0.5, xend=x+0.5, y=y+0.5, yend=lag(y)+0.5, alpha=0.2*y), size=0.2) +
  geom_segment(data=segs %>% arrange(y,x), 
               aes(x=x+0.5, xend=lag(x)+0.5, y=y+0.5, yend=y+0.5, alpha=0.2*y), size=0.2)
```

[image]

To convince yourself that the segments are mimicking the tile colors and alpha values, you can remove the tiles and plot thicker lines:

```
ggplot(volcano3d, aes(fill=z, colour=z, alpha=y)) +
  #geom_tile(colour="#FFFFFF00", aes(x, y)) +
  geom_segment(data=segs %>% arrange(x,y), 
               aes(x=x+0.5, xend=x+0.5, y=y+0.5, yend=lag(y)+0.5), size=1.5) +
  geom_segment(data=segs %>% arrange(y,x), 
               aes(x=x+0.5, xend=lag(x)+0.5, y=y+0.5, yend=y+0.5), size=1.5)
```

[image]

Here's a version with a diverging colour gradient, which creates greater contrast across the range of `z` values:

```
ggplot(volcano3d, aes(fill=z, colour=z, alpha=y)) +
  geom_tile(colour="#FFFFFF00", aes(x, y)) +
  geom_segment(data=segs %>% arrange(x,y), 
               aes(x=x+0.5, xend=x+0.5, y=y+0.5, yend=lag(y)+0.5), size=0.2) +
  geom_segment(data=segs %>% arrange(y,x), 
               aes(x=x+0.5, xend=lag(x)+0.5, y=y+0.5, yend=y+0.5), size=0.2) +
  scale_fill_gradient2(low="red", mid="yellow", high="blue", midpoint=mean(range(volcano3d$z))) +
  scale_colour_gradient2(low="red", mid="yellow", high="blue", midpoint=mean(range(volcano3d$z)))
```

[image]